# What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the curve $r(t) = a \cdot \cos(t) + b \cdot \sin(t)$ is a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

So here's what I got so far:

$r(t)$ is a circle iff $|r(t)| = \text{const.}$ iff $\sqrt{(a_1\cos(t) + b_1\sin(t))^2 + (a_2\cos(t) + b_2\sin(t))^2} = \text{const.}$

iff $$(a_1\cos(t) + b_1\sin(t))^2 + (a_2\cos(t) + b_2\sin(t))^2 = \text{const.}$$

iff $$a_1^2 \cos^2(t) + b_1^2\sin^2(t) + a_2^2\cos^2(t) + b_2^2\sin^2(t) + 2a_1b_1 \cos(t) \sin(t) + 2a_2b_2 \cos(t) \sin(t) = \text{const.}$$

iff $$a_1^2 \cos^2(t) + b_1^2\sin^2(t) + a_2^2\cos^2(t) + b_2^2\sin^2(t) + a_1b_1 \sin(2t) + a_2b_2 \sin(2t) = \text{const.}$$

iff $$a_1^2 \cos^2(t) + b_1^2\sin^2(t) + a_2^2\cos^2(t) + b_2^2\sin^2(t) + (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2) \sin(2t) = \text{const.}$$

iff $$(a_1^2 + a_2^2) \cos^2(t) + (b_1^2 + b_2^2)\sin^2(t) + (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2) \sin(2t) = \text{const.}$$

iff $$\langle a,a \rangle \cos^2(t) + \langle b,b \rangle\sin^2(t) + \langle a,b \rangle \sin(2t) = \text{const.}$$

iff $$\| a \|^2 \cos^2(t) + \| b \|^2 \sin^2(t) + \langle a,b \rangle \sin(2t) = \text{const.}$$

iff $$\| a \| \cos^2(t) + \| b \| \sin^2(t) + \langle a,b \rangle \sin(2t) = \text{const.}$$

It's easy for me to see that a sufficient condition is that the following two conditions hold

$$ \langle a,b \rangle = 0 $$ and
$$ \| a \| = \| b \| $$

Now, did I do anything wrong up to this point? If not, I am really unsure if it's also a necessary condition and if there are any more sufficient and necessary conditions.

Comment: Actually, a plane curve $\gamma$ is a (arc of) circle if and only if there is some $c$ such that $\lvert r(t)-c\rvert=const$.

Comment: *Or*, equivalently, if and only if its curvature is a non-zero constant.

Comment: What are $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$.

Comment: You have made the assumption that if it is a circle then its center must be the origin.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the matrix with columns $a,b$. Then $r(t) = A \gamma(t)$, where $\gamma(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ is the canonical parametrization of the unit circle.

The image of the unit circle under a linear transformation is an ellipse. This is a consequence of the [singular-value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition).
Therefore, the image is a circle iff the singular values of $A$ are equal.
The singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$.
Therefore, the image is a circle iff the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are equal.

If $\langle a,b \rangle = 0$, then $AA^T$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\| a \|^2$ and $\| b \|^2$. Hence your condition is sufficient.

More generally,
the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are equal [iff](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%5B%5Ba1,b1%5D,%5Ba2,b2%5D%5D+%5B%5Ba1,b1%5D,%5Ba2,b2%5D%5D%5ET)
$
(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + b_1^2 + b_2^2)^2 = 4(a_2 b_1 - a_1 b_2)^2
$.

This is an expression of the fact that $B$ has equal eigenvalues iff $(\operatorname{tr} B)^2 = 4 \det B$.

Comment: Shouldn't this boil down to $A=rU$ for an orthogonal matrix $U$ which is equivalent to $AA^T=r^2 E$?